# A positive constant don't change the Levi-Civita Connection

Tags: geometry, riemannian-geometry

In the Chow's book there is a question that I can't solve, the question is

> Let $\nabla^g$ denote the Levi-Civita connection of the metric $g$. Show that for any constant $c>0$ and metric $g$, $\nabla^{cg}=\nabla^g$.

I don't know what exactly $cg$ means. Someone has a hint?

Comment: It just means multiplication.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Please.

Comment: $g$ is a section of $(TM\otimes TM)^*$ so it is a function. $cg$ just means multiply the function $g$ by the constant $c$.

Comment: Ok, but what the relation with the connection?

Comment: They are equal, that is what you are trying to prove. Now that you know what $cg$ means, could you include in your question what you've tried so far?

Comment: I've used the koszul's formula to guarantee the uniquely of the connection. But, is this enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is a metric on a manifold $M$, then $cg$ is the metric given by : $(cg)_m(X,Y)=c\times g_m(X,Y)$ for any $X,Y\in T_mM$.

To really answer the question, you can use the existence/uniqueness property of the Levi-Cevita connection: for any $X,Y\in T_mM$, $\nabla_XY$ is uniquely determined by the equality $$\forall Z\in T_mM, \qquad 2g(\nabla_XY,Z)=X (g(Y,Z)) + Y (g(Z,X)) - Z (g(X,Y)) + g([X,Y],Z) - g([Y,Z], X) - g([X,Z], Y).$$

Comment: Do you want say if I prove (using the metric $cg$)that the right side of the equality is the same of the left one, then I've proved the assertion?

Comment: Is this enough? if yes, why?

Comment: Yes, prove that $g(\nabla^{g}_XY,Z)=g(\nabla^{cg}_XY,Z)$ for every vector fields $X,Y,Z$ starting from the equality above for example and it is over.

Comment: The equalaity don't should be  $g(\nabla^g_XY,Z)=cg(\nabla^{cg}_XY,Z)$?

Comment: If you would like to show that the vector field $\nabla^g_XY$ is the same as the vector field $\nabla^{cg}_XY$ then it sufficies to prove that $g(\nabla^{g}_XY,Z)=g(\nabla^{cg}_XY,Z)$ for any $Z$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understanding yet. Can you give some step of the proof?

Comment: You should read some formal definition of Levi-Cevita connection associated to a metric and watch closer the proof that claims the Levi-Cevita is uniquely determined by $g$. Look at wikipedia or in this document page 58 :http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Riemann.pdf

You only have to check that $\forall Z\in T_mM$, $\langle \nabla^g_XY,Z\rangle = \langle \nabla^{cg}_XY,Z\rangle$. This tells you that $\nabla^g_XY=\nabla^{cg}_XY$ for any $X,Y$ ($\langle .,.\rangle$ is a scalar product), and therefor $\nabla^g=\nabla^{cg}$.